# Android recent app detection

Tags: android, notifications

Some issue with "latest apps" software key. The problem is that it seems Android opens the application with latest intent used to open that application.
A problem would be if the user opened the application from a PendingIntent from a notification (which pops-off) and does some action specific to that notification.
Then when opening the application again from "most used" it does same actions as for notification case (may not be intended).

A work-around I can think of is to associate the notification with an ID (or other info) and keep it persisted. When opening the app from notification (we use a specific Intent action for that case) we check if we have that ID and if so, remove it and we're done. Next time when we open the application even if we have the notification action we don't care since the ID is no longer persisted.

Is there any better solution for this case? How do we know if the user opened the app from "most used"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the answer is `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY`